# Mock returned value of ResultSet inside the method to be tested that implements an interface

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock some data with Mockito for some tests, but I can't get it to work. My problem is that the value I want to mock is the return of a call inside the method I need to test.

I have a class, `MyAccessor.java` (that implements a service, `MyService.java`) that inside has a method, `getMyMethod(String value)`, and inside that method there is a call to the DB:

```
final List<MyType> results = this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new RowMapper<MyType>() {
    @Override
    public MyType mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        final int fieldA = rs.getInt("column_name_1");
        final int fieldB = rs.getInt("column_name_2");
        final int fieldC = rs.getInt("column_name_3");
        final int fieldD = rs.getInt("column_name_4");
        return new MyType(fieldA , fieldB , fieldC , fieldD);
    }
}, value);
```

There is a case where due to timeouts with the database, an empty list is returned by the rowMapper. So in that case it is not possible to do `return results.get(0)` because you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So I have a check:

```
if (!results.isEmpty()) {
    return results.get(0);
} else {
    return new MyType(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now, I want to test this particular scenario but I don't know how to mock the resultSet return so that the rowMapper returns an empty list. In my test class I have set:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { ".....", "....."})
@TestPropertySource(".....")
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTestMethod() {
        Mockito.when(this.jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT NULL LIMIT 0", new RowMapper<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        })).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());

        MyType result = this.myService.getMyMethod("value");
        assertEquals(0, result.getFieldA());
        assertEquals(0, result.getFieldB());
        assertEquals(0, result.getFieldC());
        assertEquals(0, result.getFieldD());
    }
}
```

But the test fails because the result returned is from the database instead of an empty list to test the timeout case.

I think the problem may be because I'm injecting the mock in the service interface instead of the implementation, but I wanted to know if it can be done somehow so I don't have to test the mock for each implementation of that interface.

Or maybe I am using the Mockito framework wrong and in that case, how can I test correctly?

Regads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was injecting the mock in the interface and not in the implementation of the interface. So I had to change:

```
@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

to:

```
@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private MyAccessor myAccessor;

@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

And inside the test this:

```
MyType result = this.myService.getMyMethod("value");
```

to:

```
MyType result = this.myAccessor.getMyMethod("value");
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, without having to instantiate all the implementations that the service may have.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like:

```
@Test
public void myTestMethod() {
    Mockito.when(this.jdbcTemplate.query(eq("SELECT NULL LIMIT 0"), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))
           .thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());
}
```

Reason is because when mocking, you were saying only to return the empty list if both arguments to the `query` is exactly as you defined. In your case, you don't care about the exact instance of `RowMapper`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer but doing this I get an error: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded. I found the problem, I was injecting the mock in the interface and not in the implementation of the interface.

Comment: Did you have ```eq``` around the SQL string? Just for future reference, that error usually suggest a mix of raw types with matchers.